# "gestehen" vs. "eingestehen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

DUDEN, DWDS und Wiktionary betrachten diese Verben als Synonyme. Hier https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idForum=4&idThread=466117&lp=ende&lang=de habe ich jedoch nachgelesen, dass der Unterschied darin liegt, ob man etwas "öffentlich" zugibt (z. B. ein Verbrechen bei der Polizei gestehen) oder sich selbst etwas eingesteht.

Im unten stehenden Kommentar (s. Leo-Link) wird zwar widersprochen, aber ich fand ihn nur noch verwirrend.

Ich habe hier einige Beispielsätze gesammelt:

(1) Der Tatverdächtige hat den Mord gestanden.

(2) Hör mal, ich muss dir etwas gestehen.

(3) Ich muss zu meiner Schande gestehen, dass ...

(4) Ich muss gestehen, du siehst heute Abend fabelhaft aus!

Wäre der Gebrauch des Verbs *eingestehen* in diesen Sätzen ebenfalls möglich? Würdet Ihr die auf Leo vertretene Auffassung bestätigen?

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 2):

DWDS beschreibt mein intuitives Verständnis der beiden Begriffe ganz gut:

[gestehen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gestehen) = eine Schuld, ein Vergehen zugeben. Da steht also die Sachlichkeit im Vordergrung.

[eingestehen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/eingestehen) = etwas mit Überwindung zugeben.

Dem stehen die Substanive Geständnis und Eingeständnis zur Seite, letzteres als das mit Überwindung gemachte Geständnis. Ich würde jetzt aus der Spracherfahrung einräumen daß die Grenzen zwischen den beiden Begrifflichkeiten fließend sind.

Mit *Überwindung* ist wohl eher ein innerer Zwiespalt als ein äußerer Zwang gemeint, schließlich kann ein Geständnis ja auch unter Zwang jemandem entrungen werden.

Besipiel:

> "Das Geständnis sprudelte nur so aus ihm heraus."

> "Sie konnte sich schließlich überwinden und gestand den Sachverhalt ein."

Comment: To summarize in English, you're saying that *eingestehen* is done with reluctance, so it's closer to "admit" than "confess"; is that right? In the examples I looked at, it seems *eingestehen* is more likely to happen in a public context, while *gestehen* often happens in a private conversation. But that seems to be consistent with what you're saying.

Comment: Die Bedeutung von »eingestehen« ist ganz gut getroffen, aber die ersten drei Beispiele hören sich komisch an, ich würde alle drei mit »gestehen« formulieren.

Comment: @RDBury: Yep, I think you got the gist of it. But I don't feel total consistency, since both terms are used in public (e.g. official legal) contexts as well as private. It seems to be more like "it needed a few convincing arguments" for an Eingeständnis. I have overworked the answer.

Comment: @Raketenolli: Ja, ich denke auch daß es eine Überdeckung gibt und beide Termini mitunter austauschbar verwendet werden können. Ich finde solche Feinheiten aber manchmal auch 'gehobenen Sprachgebrauch' :-)